# Crear una lista de objetos de una clase a raiz de otra lista de otra clase

Tags: java, poo, lista

Voy a intentar explicarme lo mejor posible ya que es lioso y me explico muy mal jaja

Tengo una clase pongamos llamada "Clase_A".
Dentro de esa clase tengo un par de variables de tipo "Clase_B" rollo:

```
protected Clase_B grupo1;
protected Clase_B grupo 2;
```

Y dentro de Clase_B tengo otras cuantas estilo:

```
public String nombre;
public String apellidos;
public int edad;
```

etc.

Y luego tengo una lista del estilo "List lista" con varios registros de varias filas que me devuelve una query.

Osea que en resumen tengo una lista de objetos dentro con dos objetos de la clase Clase_A que a su vez tienen dentro variables de la clase Clase_B.

El tema es que de la Clase_B no se rellenan todas las variables con la query, algunas si y algunas no. He creado una clase llamada "Clase_C" con otro par de variables como las de la Clase_B pero solo las que necesito. Y necesito sacar de la lista "List" las variables concretas que necesito y meterlas dentro de la nueva lista "List". He intentado de todo y no lo consigo, alguno sabria como hacerlo? Y repito que me explico muy mal asi que cualquier duda decidme e intento explicarlo mejor jajaja Un saludo! Y muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Al final he conseguido resolverlo, por si a alguien le sirve lo que he hecho es instanciar un objeto de la clase "Clase_C" e ir sacando y guardando en dicha clase los valores de la lista que me interesaban y al final hacer un "add" a la nueva lista del objeto, dentro de un bucle for para sacar todas las filas claro, aun asi gracias!